# why isn't my thread joinable in perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl

I wrote a very short script with Perl and I used `multi-thread` in it.

My problem is, the thread I created is not `joinable`. So I am wondering, what is the condition to make thread joinable?

What is the limit of a thread in Perl?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
#
use lib "$::XCATROOT/lib/perl";
use strict;
use threads;
use Safe;

sub test
{
    my $parm = shift; 
}
my $newchassis = ["1", "2", "3"];
my @snmp_threads ;

for my $item (@$newchassis)
{
    my $thread =  threads->create(\&test, $item);
    push @snmp_threads, $thread;
}

for my $t (@snmp_threads)
{
    $t->join();
}
```

This can be very tricky as it works find on RHEL 6.3 and but fails on SLES 11sp2.

Comment: Please, show the code.

Comment: We need to see your code, to see what's happening ..

Comment: I can not show you code, so may I know the pre-condition of a joinable thread?

Comment: If you can't show us the exact code, can you show us an example code that has the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no code, i will go ahead and assume that you are using `join foreach @threads;` for joining the threads. Now the joining of the threads depends on the post processing. Without seeing your code it's difficult to know, what you are doing. But how it works is that :

1. If the post-processing step needs all threads to finish before
   beginning work, then the wait for individual threads is unavoidable.
2. If the post-processing step is specific to the results of each
   thread, it should be possible to make the post-processing part of
   the thread itself.
3. In both cases, `$_->join foreach @threads;` is the way to go.
4. If there is no need to wait for the threads to finish, use the
   detach command instead of join. However, any results that the
   threads may return will be discarded.

Are you sure, you have provided a valid  post processing scenario for your activity ?

Comment: Hi @the-dark-knight, I have appended some sample code. Please check.